# What is an effective way to evaluate and assess employees on a non-management career track?

Tags: management, career-development

My company is growing pretty quickly, and I'd like to make sure we have a career path that lets people move up without tying that exclusively to management roles.

I'm in control of this, and am excited about implementing this. I am having some trouble figuring out how to actually figure out a fair and empirical way to determine whether people should get a promotion.

This is extremely easy with management-track people: the more people who exist under you in the org chart, the higher you are. (E.g., the CEO who indirectly manages everyone is clearly doing something more complicated than a team lead with four people under her.) It's more difficult when it's a product manager who starts managing one of our products, and then keeps managing that product, but hopefully better.

I'm pretty hesitant to use something like volume of features or bugs (not) shipped because they're so easy to game and create perverse incentives. It's also possible these may not actually be causally linked with an individual: maybe a salesperson is more effective not because of his individual effort, but because his manager has built a more effective plan and he's still executing at the same level.

What do big companies that have figured this out do?

My current thoughts are around ways these people demonstrate they're solving harder problems. E.g., are they writing code that's more central to the system and used by more people, or are they speaking at conferences.

Comment: Do they do the job you hired them for in the time-frame you expect?  That's one way.

Comment: I don’t understand how “the more people who exist under you in the org chart, the higher you go” corresponds with “figure out whether people should get a promotion in a fair and empirical way”. Are you trying to figure out how to measure their performance or give them responsibilities commensurate  with their title?

Comment: This seems somewhat backwards to me.  Developers who write code are fairly easy to evaluate in a number of ways.  Are they solving the problems?  Are they good at tackling new challenges?  Does the code they write stand the test of time?  Are they easy to work with?  For managers, it can be a lot tougher to tell whether they are actively helping the company, or just good at acting like a manager.  
 Their "product" is much less tangible.

Comment: Have you considered asking your employees?

Comment: If you solve this problem (objective assessment and measurement of a creative process, looking at people who may well be more intelligent and informed than the assessors) you should get a Nobel prize.

Comment: Take a look at progression frameworks - https://www.progression.fyi/ has a great collection of companies doing that and lots of explanation. Reading through them helps. I personally like https://progression.monzo.com/ a lot. I might write an answer later.

Comment: If you start dishing out promotions based on which features get used more then you are going to annoy people fast. Common features are usually pretty simple, and the complex ones tend to be used by less users. It sounds like you don't have any experience with software development, so you should probably stay well clear of trying to find an answer that is based on technical achievements. What you need to do is define the roles your company needs (not random ones for the sake of progression), and determine the qualities required of those roles. Then look for those qualities when promoting.

Comment: I think the only way to find a way to define different levels and their competencies would be to consult with domain experts (ideally those inside your company), look at what your company needs and/or check what other companies are doing for the specific role that you're interested in. Most/all of these competencies would be more open-ended and subjective than "manages X people" (which seems like a problematic measure anyway, since it doesn't say much about how good they are at managing any of those people).

Comment: Less concrete, but Lethain's https://staffeng.com/ and lethain.com itself have a lot of useful guidance on the IC track, how to frame it and how it usually lands.

Comment: "big companies that have figured this out" — it's quite possible no such companies exist.

Comment: Be VERY careful of that 'size of your team' metric for management, it encourages hiring and failing that poaching without due consideration for business need. You really want to be using a much more behaviour based set of assessments, really for both managers and technical folks. For management I would favour asking both other managers and their reports how this person helps them to get things done, for technical roles in addition to the tech stuff, poke into mentoring and niche business expertise, usually how you differentiate people once they get basically competent at what you do.

Comment: Yes, sorry. By size of team I meant more that there's a clear progression from, say, team lead (managing only individual contributors) to VP (managing managers) to CEO (managing everyone). I.e., size of team not necessarily meaning people directly managed. Tried to clarify in the question text.

Comment: *the CEO who indirectly manages everyone is clearly doing something more complicated than a team lead with four people under her* - I disagree. The CEO is taking on more *responsibility* but that doesn't necessarily equate to more *complexity*. If anything, jobs seem to me to get *simpler* as you go up the tree

Comment: If anyone is curious, this is where we wound up: https://blog.dev.proton.ai/careers/

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> What do big companies that have figured this out do?

They use **progression frameworks**. Take a look at [progression.fyi](https://www.progression.fyi/) to start with.

The basic concept is that people know themselves where they stand and what is expected of them to progress. It empowers them to chose their own role and makes the whole process very transparent.

You typically have a handful of areas that are used to examine people's behaviour. I like [the ones Monzo use for technical people](https://progression.monzo.com/engineering/backend):

> The framework covers all the things we’re looking for from engineers
> at Monzo. We’re interested in these five elements:
>
> - Mastery - Your Monzo knowledge and technical capability
> - Impact - The size, scope and value of what you deliver
> - Influence - How you change the world around you for the better
> - Comms & Feedback - How you interact with others
> - Leadership - How people around you become better and more impactful

Next you define a couple of levels, which would have traditionally been *Junior*, *Mid-Level*, *Senior* and so on. Companies often have 4 to 6 of these, and sometimes only call them by their number, or as *tier* something.

For each level, there are certain behaviours and skills for every area mentioned above. These are the things that someone should know and do when they are in that level.

I'm going to stick with Monzo and compare three levels here as an example. See the above link for more. We're going to use *Influence*.

On level one, which is apparently very junior, there is this:

> - Improves documentation that is incorrect

Level two of six has this:

> - Proactively raises issues they spot in retrospectives

But on level three, things are starting to look different:

> - Provides valuable input to proposals from their team
> - Proactively improves modules, services, systems and codebases they encounter, 'this doesn't make sense, I'm going to do something about it'
> - Contributes to scaling engineering hiring (e.g. leads calls, does onsite interviews)
> - Builds simple tools or iterates existing tools for the benefit of all engineers

You can see how the responsibilities would grow with that, but also the skills and aptitudes need to grow.

Many organisations allow different ranks within each of these levels to distinguish pay grades for example. So someone who is happy doing just coding can advance and get more reach in their role and be more distinguished and important for the organisation without joining a management track.

What's really important for implementing something like this is that the entire organisation needs to be on board, if you want to make it large scale. The company values need to line up with this kind of transparency.

> My current thoughts are around ways these people demonstrate they're solving harder problems. E.g., are they writing code that's more central to the system and used by more people, or are they speaking at conferences.

These all nicely map to the different elements. Someone who speaks at conferences has a higher *impact* and a greater *influence* than someone who doesn't. Someone who writes new code on a core system has more *impact* than someone who writes integrations for 3rd party systems. Again, if you work though the different tiers on the Monzo framework, not only for backend developer but also for product people or even HR, this will become very obvious.

**How to set this up**

To set this up from scratch in an existing part of your org, or even the entire org, I would suggest you find people to represent the different existing roles and quiz them about what they do, and how they rate themselves in that. Make it clear that this is in no way meant to play people against each other or question whether they are doing enough work. Also make sure that pay reviews don't happen immediately once you're done. People might have been hired on different salaries because of the way they negotiated. If you find out that someone is on too high a salary, freeze it and work with them to get them to perform at that salary rather than cutting it, or you will very likely lose that person.

If that can't be done you can still use the idea of a progression framework to run your own, small-scale program inside your department or part of your company.

I have implemented a similar system for the trainee program I run in my organisation as a development mentor, with three levels that end at someone outgrowing the *Junior Developer* role, which I heavily based on Monzo and a few others. I've spoken about that [in German at the German Perl Workshop 2020](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zq6g2OPXlx0), but unfortunately haven't had a chance yet to get an English language recording.

Disclaimer: I do not work at Monzo and there is no affiliation.

Comment: This deserves to be the top answer.

Comment: This is a great start, but the top levels seem to me to be getting into management. E.g. “is the accountable exec”, “delegates to make better use of time”

Comment: @Tim I suppose there always is an exec at the top. But ideally you want your CTO or VP Engineering to come from a technical track, don't you? Not all managers are _just_ managers. ;)

Answer (score 84):

Any system will be gamed, *especially* by nerdy types like software engineers. They will make it a sport. Any metric you find will be exploited. Not even for malicious intent, but just to show you that it is possible. So finding a "fair metric" is next to impossible and trying to do so is a hard and unrewarding process. I would suggest you don't go there.

I have never found the need for more than 3 levels of any job: Junior, Mid-level and Senior.

A junior needs help in their own job. A mid-level can do their own job quite well without help. A senior can do their own job well *and* help out the juniors.

Anything more and we are probably talking about a different job altogether. For example you may have an systems architect. But that is not just a "better than senior developer", it's actually a different job with different requirements.

Any decent manager should know who in their team falls into which category, without metrics to look at. If they don't, they don't deserve to be their manager.

Comment: What's the size of your company and how many people are you leading?

Comment: But you could add "Chief" or "Consultant" roles for the most talented people, with the assumption that that would be working across multiple projects, not just on one.

Comment: The senior you describe is hit pretty fast, in terms of a career. I believe the idea of a "technical" track is to continue the chain higher. But you're right, most places don't do that.

Comment: Simple and workable job levels

Comment: @Mavrik I have worked in companies of 50+ people and in corporate behemoths of 126,447 employees (had to look that up, never saw more than about 500 of them personally). I have managed between 0 and 13 people. I have been part of 50 person teams, and they were a mess because no manager can really manage 50 direct employees well. I'm not sure how that helps you though.

Comment: @NathanCooper Well, yes, for developers I would expect that to happen between 5 and 15 years. But I don't believe in giving out job titles like "chief supreme uber developer of doom" just because they did a good developer job for 40 years. If their day to day work is developer, then they are a senior developer. If they moved to systems architecture or project management or even management, then their job title changes. I am not saying that all senior developers are on the same pay grade by the way. Pay is a function of demand and supply, job title is the description of the job one does.

Comment: @nvoigt The problem is that generally pay grades are very often tied to a large degree to the job title in my experience. Sure there's some wiggle room - but do you have senior developers that earn more than double that of another senior developer?

Comment: @Voo Certainly not. But why would I pay double for the same job? If they really deserve double the salary, then probably because they do a different job. If for example you pay your SAP specialists double the money you pay your JS developers, then that's apparently two different jobs with different requirements.

Comment: @nvoigt And that thinking is how many excellent developers end up as mediocre managers because that's the only progression the company offers.

Comment: It sounds like you've only worked at small companies without particularly clearly defined roles or ones where people in technical roles are forced into management to progress. Companies like Google have a whole lot more than 3 Software Engineer levels. Also, if the evaluation criteria you use corresponds to what you expect from people at some level, then the only way to "game" that would be by actually performing at that level. Like if you say a senior should "help out the juniors", then one can "game" that by helping out juniors and thus do what you want a senior to do

Comment: @BernhardBarker I guess you misunderstood. A senior is someone who is able and willing to help juniors. If a mid-level is able to and willing to help juniors, then they are a senior, there is no "gaming" of any system there. Please note that "helping" means training and explanations so the junior can advance to mid-level, not "I'll help you, give me half your work".

Comment: As far as size goes, I had to look it up, Google is actually 3.8 percent larger than my former employer. So yeah... I guess I only worked for corporate overloads smaller than Google. If Google wants to name their jobs "Developer 1-27" that's their problem. I prefer Developer, Systems Architect, Database Admin, Database Architect, SAP specialist, Security specialist etc and all those in Junior/Mid/Senior. Because they aren't interchangeable, they aren't all "developer", they aren't just "better developer level 7", they are separate jobs with separate hiring requirements.

Comment: @nvoigt "If a mid-level is able to and willing to help juniors, then they are a senior" - that's my point. Attempts to game the system just results in them doing what you want them to do if your evaluation criteria are reasonable.

Comment: That's in line with academic models of skill and generally reasonable but I am surprised you have so much trouble understanding the issues it can present for employee retention and reward structure.

Comment: 3 levels?  Junior, Mid, Senior, Principal, Senior Principal, Fellow, probably Senior Fellow and Principal Fellow if more room is needed or "Distinguished Fellow" in lieu of S/P Fellow.  Also a lot of govt or related employers do a I-IV system.

Comment: @nvoigt I haven't worked at google, but my impression was that there are plenty of different titles based on what kind of technical work you're doing. The 11 (really 8 in practice) levels  are just that, a rough attempt at standardising what *level* you're working at in your respective domain.

Comment: @nvoigt how would your junior/senior etc categories for engineers map to the equivalents for managers. Eg. Take the most senior management position sub-board level, what might that and the parallel engineer position be called? How does that mapping work with multiple management levels but only 3 engineer levels?

Comment: @nvoigt At the big tech companies, the people on the higher levels than senior basically impact much more people. For example, a senior engineer will probably impact his team and a few close teams, while a principal engineer and above will drive improvements and good practices at a business unit level (likely affecting 1000+ people). And yeah, those levels don't prevent you from having separate roles, that's not what it's about, although they do conflate roles since they are able to hire people who will be good at e.g. both being a developer and architect.

Comment: Indeed, I'm trying to find a track with enough range that someone who's not a manager could be paid as much and have as much prestige as a senior VP. Also, not necessarily looking for a metric (in the sense of a number), so much as a clear set of criteria (could be more qualitative) to make sure we're consistent and fair.

Answer (score 10):

It has been my experience that when goals are set, and reviews are done which outline whether an employee meets or exceeds expectations you can start to determine tracks at that point.  If an employee is exceeding expectations, then a new title and pay raise are in order.

Dev1, Dev2, et cet.  In addition, you can track an employee into areas where more sophisticated or technical work is required.  They do this in the trades all the time.  An apprentice, journeyman, and master plumber are all rises in rank.

The key is to have the progression defined, an clear list of qualifications to fit that role, and a path laid out to attain that level.

The maritime industry is also one to look at for non-managerial progressions, where time and competence earns a rise in pay and responsibilities.  Anyone could sign on as a "boy", and could become an ordinary seaman, and eventually an "able bodied seaman".

So, mimicking a structure of the trades would do best for you.

It's harder to game a system when you're not going by best throughput, or most number of bug fixes, but rather a fixed set of core competencies.

The effect of this is twofold:

First, it encourages people to stay with your company as they see a progression open to them

Second, it helps management in reviews, as they can point out what core competencies of the next level an employee already has, and what they need to develop.

Of course, the real hard work is going to be setting those ratings/ranks and what core competencies are required for each.

Now, another way this could help is if you have someone who is very strong in some competencies, but weak in others for their chosen path, but may make them a better fit for a different path.  This again helps with retention and optimal utilization of employees.

**TLDR:  Look at how the trades, such as plumber, electrician, and the maritime trades and draw inspiration from them**

Comment: Yes, trades has a centuries old time tested progression

Answer (score 2):

I think you should *also* look at how your system deals with people who aren't burning with ambition. People who are happy to have a stable job they're good at. Such people can be a stable core that keeps a department working smoothly over the years while others aim to climb the ladder. Especially in jobs that may not really have that much growth potential in them.

When I worked in tech support, half the people working there were temps - mostly STEM students. They were smart, inquisitive, good problem solvers. But they tended to stay there for only half a year, two years tops really, and then they moved on to bigger and better things. The *other* half of the crew were lifers, who just came in, did their job from 9 to 5 and went home. Most had hobbies that they lived for - they didn't live for their job, but it was stable, and something they were good at. They carried most of the real savvy and institutional knowledge. The combination of these two types of people made it a really effective tech support desk. We were able to both learn new things but also didn't have to re-invent the wheel all the time.

Comment: I think that sort of company is just what you get when you don't have a good system of progression for non-managers. The good people leave. They should be asking themselves what the other companies offer that makes their jobs 'bigger and better', and why losing all that experience isn't seen as a problem.

Comment: This is a great point: not everyone wants to move up. But at the same time, yes, my big concern here is making sure all the people who want to move up actually have a path that works for them.

Answer (score 1):

## Rebuild Your Team

Evaluating career levels/promotions boils down to imposing some ordering on the performance of employees.  It seems like a pretty difficult problem to solve from first principles, but it's something you can do in less than 5 minutes if I phrase it this way: "Your boss has just offered you a high-stakes, high-visibility project that will get you a guaranteed promotion if you deliver.  At the same time, you need to keep the lights on and keep other product owners happy, so you can't put your entire team on this project.  Under these conditions, which people would you choose for the elite team, the business-as-usual team, and the maintenance team, and why?"  If you can't answer this question with less than 5 minutes of reflection, you probably aren't a very good manager and are not qualified for the task that's been given to you.  When you start to justify why you would put a given team member on team A vs. B vs. C, you start to realize the attributes that *you* value and which *you* perceive to be essential to good delivery.  However, you will probably notice that the combinations of attributes varies from person to person even on the same team, and this is where it gets complicated.

You can and *should* solicit feedback from the engineers themselves (you didn't say what industry you were in, but your language strongly implies engineering in general, and software engineering in particular).  Not only do they certainly have some strong opinions, but if their views don't line up with yours, that's a big red flag that you need to spend more time understanding their perspective.  One way to do that is to pose the same question to them, as a survey with private responses.  My guess is that you will find a surprising amount of uniformity in the responses, because folks generally have an intuitive perspective of levelling.  You can frame this survey as a kind of informal peer review that does not correspond to any actual restructuring.  Be honest and say that you are asking for their help in formulating a levelling guide, and this is one step in the process.  Some of them will probably want to give you direct feedback on defining levels, which you should incorporate.

Also, you need to expand your scope by considering folks outside of your team.  If you could poach staff from another team, which ones would you go after first, and why?  Who are your rock stars that you jealously guard from poaching?  Who would you be happy to lose?  Which folks around the company are in demand by other managers?  Talk to other managers and see if your perspectives align (ask them what their company-wide dream team would look like, etc.).  Obviously, there will be both similarities and differences among managers, but also across organizations which have different demands, products, and responsibilities.  You need to take into account the varying motivations when evaluating feedback.

## Define Levels

I think [simbabque's answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/169017/105198) covers this decently well.  I agree that Monzo's definitions are clear, clean, and a good example to help you make sure you didn't miss anything obvious.  Of course, you will want to adapt it for your company/industry, but that should be pretty easy.

What I will add is that while many large companies define parallel tracks for managers vs. individual contributors, those same companies usually stop the IC track well short of the highest manager levels.  Obviously, few CEOs will accept an IC that is considered a direct peer on the org chart.  And some companies will argue that when an IC gets to a certain level, the scope of their responsibilities is so broad as to be equivalent to a [S]VP/President anyway, so might as well give them a management title.  I personally think this is a mistake, because while the broad scope may be true, people who wish to fill those roles don't necessarily want to lead an entire VP org or larger, and giving them a title without an org dilutes the levelling definitions for VP+.

Thus, if your company has a substantial engineering force and many manager levels, I would suggest that you push to define parallel IC levels as high as the upper management will tolerate.  Even if you have no engineers who are currently qualified to fill such positions, defining them gives folks something to aspire to and provides more steps on the career path than just plateauing at your typical IC mid-level cap (somewhere near the middle of middle management).

What should an IC at such a level do?  Well, they shouldn't just be heads-down working on their pet projects with no oversight.  They should be peeping in on significant projects being executed around the company, offering consultation and working to provide consistency around design and architecture across orgs.  But they should also be able to pop into any meeting of same-level executives and give a technical briefing about the projects managers wish to discuss.  Many times managers conceive of project ideas with little engineering input, and invent fanciful deadlines and expectations.  Other times, managers will oversell a project because they are a smooth talker, and a credible technical voice can lend a more realistic perspective without looking like managers sniping each other for position (because other managers can often tell when a project is getting oversold, but calling that out comes with political consequences).

Many times there are broad technology choices which have impact across the whole company, and leaving these decisions to managers who consult with their tech experts turns it into political football rather than a pursuit of the best solution.  Having high-level ICs to offer technical perspective can mean the difference between choosing the best solution vs. choosing the solution championed by the most influential up-n-coming manager whose IC rock star chose it as their pet project.  But that also means making sure that you promote the best people to such levels, exactly because their actions can have an outsized effect on the rest of the company.

## Challenge Assumptions

I would also encourage you to rethink the idea that "more reports == better manager".  I think most folks here can tell you about a manager who ran a large org, but poorly.  The reasons for getting promoted are sometimes only tenuously related to performance, and actually dominated by networking and personal connections.  The fact that you led with that example suggests that perhaps you are not willing to think deeply enough about the topic to do a good job.  Try to think if you can identify any managers you know who are running an org which is "too big for their britches".  I would be surprised if you can't name any.  Then think about how they got there.

My personal yardstick for "good managers" is: "promotes good people, and weeds out the bad apples."  Promoting good people sounds easy, and yet, I can name lots of times when I saw a less-than-good person get promoted because they are good at "personal sales" more than actual performance.  But even more important than promoting good people is getting rid of bad apples.  This is one of the hardest, least appreciated aspects of being a manager.  Bad managers know when they have someone who is slowly (or quickly) poisoning their team, but simply don't act because they lack the spine and wish to avoid conflict.  Of course, a good manager has to *know* when such a person is killing their team, their org, the manager's reputation, etc.  But acting on it is even more challenging, because it involves doing something unpleasant with a person who is, by definition, not fun to deal with.

Sometimes, the bad actor is just on the wrong team, has personality clashes, and could succeed on another team.  Finding that other team and helping them to transition successfully is the mark of a truly great manager.  That's turning an all-around bad into a win-win.  Other times, the person is just a bad apple, and needs to leave the company for the good of the company.  Getting rid of those folks is both the least pleasant and most difficult task for any manager.  But the managers I respected the most are ones who did exactly that.  Getting rid of a bad apple can improve the quality of life for dozens of employees, no matter how much it sucks.

You may find, when talking to your ICs about levelling ideas, that some things you think are important really aren't important to them, and the things they bring up may be surprising and enlightening to you.  Unless you have already excelled in their role and have substantial experience, you should listen to their feedback carefully and with an open mind.  After all, when *you* choose to promote someone based on the levels you helped create, you want everyone on your team to say: "Yeah, that was a good promotion.  I see a clear path for myself here."  If that happens, you'll know you succeeded.  The peers are often the final judge.

Answer (score -5):

#### Seniority.

A classic metric for determining progression in non-management roles is seniority - how long an employee has been working in a particular role, either at a particular organization, or in the industry in general. While it does have the downside of only being loosely coupled with the sorts of improved competence you actually want to measure, it does have the advantage of being both easy to measure and difficult for employees to game.

Comment: Seniority is a terrible metric, especially in the tech fields.

Comment: "how long an employee has been working in a particular role" that is a *terrible* metric. I have seen people unable to tie their shoes after ten years in the job and brilliant people that with 1-2 years of experience easily surpassed them. It's a government metric. Where you don't have to actually *perform*, but just have to wait out your time. There is a reason most public administration is pretty crappy.

Comment: @nvoigt Like I said, it's only loosely coupled with the things you're actually interested in, but there is some degree of coupling because of things like developing domain knowledge/practicing skills and developing knowledge of the business.

Comment: I've heard the description "1 year of experience repeated 10 times" - not everyone learns at the same rate.

Comment: While seniority has many flaws, one especially problematic feature of seniority is how it acts as a motivator.  You're either firing otherwise-satisfied juniors or you're paying/using juniors as though they were senior.  Further, employees with senior-level skills will feel unappreciated; they'll either leave or lower their performance.  That said, there is *some* value in seniority-based pay rewards (i.e., giving a yearly pay raise): Even if an employee's skill grows slowly or not at all, their domain knowledge probably *will* grow (and you can't hire that out).

Comment: @MSalters that phrase is horrifyingly accurate.  I've cleaned up so many messes by people with FAR more seniority than I.  Also, I have less seniority than most people in my current company, but I've got decades more experience than at least 75% of them, and my experience has been working in some rough environments where I had to innovate.